# ROSRUN missing command

Tags: rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On an Ubuntu 14.04 with Indigo (installed a while ago) and recently updated to catkin_tools,
I miss the `rosrun` command, cant run any node, the error in terminal is **rosrun: command not found**,
while all other other commands are present:

```
rosbag                        roslocate
rosclean                      rosmaster
rosco                         rosmsg
rosconsole                    rosmsg-proto
roscore                       rosnode
rosdep                        rospack
rosdep-source                 rosparam
rosdistro_build_cache         rosservice
rosdistro_migrate_to_rep_141  rossrv
rosdistro_migrate_to_rep_143  rosstack
rosdistro_reformat            rostest
rosgraph                      rostopic
rosinstall                    rosunit
roslaunch                     rosversion
roslaunch-complete            rosws
roslaunch-deps                roswtf
roslaunch-logs
```

In my `.bashrc` I have:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash 
source TE_workspace/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:~/TE_workspace/src
```

where `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is after exporting `/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks:/home/user/TE_workspace/src`

What am I missing? What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219001/rosrun-missing-command/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have the `ros-indigo-rosbash` package installed?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-10-12**:
Thanks, that pkg was missing. It should had been installed earlier. I found out that a jade was also installed and I uninstalled recently could that action remove also `rosbash`? Different distro should not do something like that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-12**:
I don't know, that would completely depend on how you uninstalled, what commands you used, etc.

I do know that 'updating to catkin_tools' has nothing to do with it: you cannot actually 'upgrade' to it, as it is a stand-alone package, and orthogonal to any other ROS pkgs installed.